# Kali linux failed after upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, wget, recovery

My Kali stopped working after upgrade.
I run it in recovery mode, and it seems that basic communication (http) packages have some problem.

When I try wget or curl I get:

`relocation error /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference`

I guess that some files are corrupted but cannot find a way to detect all the corrupted, and to replace them. Of course, I need to do it manually (e.g., from USB), as I can't use wget and similar commands.

Thanks!

Comment: My Kali Linux has the same exact issue. Happened after I updated the Metasploit Framework. Hopefully someone will has a solution or knows how to fix this.

Comment: @Aura I managed to fix it! see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to fix it:

1. From another computer I downloaded the libidn2.so.0 deb file and moved it to USB.
2. In recovery-mode, I succeeded to offline replace it with my file. Now wget, curl and the other networking command work!
3. I ran update and upgrade successfully and installed gnome. (after the upgrade, I had to re-install again libidn2.so.0).
4. Reboot and login page pops up (although it took longer than I used to).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know how it went.

Comment: I had this happen after some upgrades on my Powerbook (which is running Debian). I cross compiled gnutls and libidn for it and that fixed it here (for now).

Answer (score 8):

Ok here is the fix that worked for me:

My box was running live when I did this.

First download deb to another host:

> wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb

Then SCP that up to the box that is having issues.

Once the file is up on the box. Run this:

> sudo dpkg -i /tmp/libidn2-0_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb

This was a downgrade for me and then I was able to update (apt-get) without issue.

At this point I do not know of any issues this will cause. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have been struggling with this for the past 2 days.

Comment: Also affects Ubuntu 18.04 using ondrej/php repository

Workaround is to downgrade libidn2-0 and mark the package as held.

Package source is https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libidn2-0

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-mark hold libidn2-0
```

For cross reference the issue in ondrej
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1247

Comment: This error compromises almost everything. Thank you master