# Relocation error: NETTLE_6 not defined in file libnettle.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: linux, debian, wget, apt

I have recently upgraded from Debian 9 to Debian 10 but right after that apt, wget and many other packages stopped working correctly.

This is what I get when I try to use any of those

```
wget: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol nettle_cfb_decrypt version NETTLE_6 not defined in file libnettle.so.6 with link time reference
```

I found a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1466648/kali-linux-failed-after-upgrade) to mine in here, but installing libnettle 6 did not change anything (it was already installed).

```
find /usr/ -name 'libnettle*'                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
/usr/share/doc/libnettle6  
/usr/local/lib/libnettle.a  
/usr/local/lib/libnettle.so.6.3
/usr/local/lib/libnettle.so
/usr/local/lib/libnettle.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.5
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, you can try uninstalling the alien files in /usr/local/lib/

Comment: Removing them solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Knud Larsen](https://superuser.com/users/525523/knud-larsen), deleting the older libnettle files in `/usr/local/lib` solved the issue.